# Differentiating real valued vector functions.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vector-analysis

If $v(a,b,c): \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3 $ and $ f: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(v) = v \cdot v $  (dot product) , what is $\frac{\partial f}{\partial a}$?

Chain rule attempt:

$\frac{df}{dv} = 2v$ and so $\frac{\partial f}{\partial a} = 2v \cdot \frac{\partial v}{\partial a} $? I dont think this is correct unfortunately. Could someone give me some pointers please :)

Comment: We have $(v\cdot u )' = v' \cdot u + v \cdot u'$ just like for the usual product.

Comment: There's a product rule for dot products, too. ($u\cdot v)'=u'\cdot v+u\cdot v'$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is correct. But if we want to approach it in your chain rule way, you should clarify which is a column and which is a row vector. Usually, we understand $v$ as a column vector and the differential as a row vector. So
$$
Df(x) = 2x^\top.
$$
Then, by chain rule we have
$$
D(f\circ v)(a, b, c) = Df(v(a, b, c)) \cdot Dv(a, b, c) = 2v(a, b, c)^\top Dv(a, b, c)
$$
So
$$
\partial_a (f \circ v)(a, b, c) = (D(f \circ v)(a, b, c))_1 = 2v(a, b, c)^\top \partial_a v(a, b, c)= 2v^\top \partial_a v.
$$

Answer (score 2):

We have $v(a,b,c) = (v_1(a,b,c), v_2(a,b,c), v_3(a,b,c))$ and $f(v) = |v|^2 =  v_1^2 + v_2^2 + v_3^2$. Now apply the chain rule to each summand.